# Unable to connect MS SQL Server installed in EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, windows-firewall

[image]I have an t3.xlarge instance on EC2. In this EC2 I have installed the SQL SERVER
2019 Express with Advance Option to runs the SSRS. I can successfully connect this SQL Server with my non-AWS local area network but this possible whenever I disable my Windows Firewall. The problem is there when I disable the Windows Firewall I am not able to connect the DB with my LAN.

What I have already did

1. Made the entries for port 1433,1434 and 80 in the inbound rule EC2 Windows Firewall and Advance Security.
2. Made the entries for port 1433,1434 and 80 in the outbound rule EC2 Windows Firewall and Advance Security.
3. Made the entries for port 1433,1434 and 80 in the inbound rule EC2 Security Group.
4. Made the entries for port 1433,1434 and 80 in the outbound rule EC2 Security Group.
5. All of my SQL Server Configuration is enabled (TCP/IP).

[image]

Comment: By LAN, do you mean your local non-AWS computer that isn't on the same VPC as the EC2? I suggest you clearly describe the nodes involved and their connectivity.

Comment: hey @Nick.McDermaid, above I am talking about the my non aws LAN. Thanks for the suggestion.